# Refactor this until statement to be more compact?

Tags: ruby, loops

So I have the following unless loop:

```
offset = 0
count = false
until count == 0
  offset += 100
  count = ThirdPartyApi.all(offset: offset)

  # Do other things within the loop
end
```

Basically what it does is the count from `ThirdPartyApi.all` gets reduces as the offset increases and once there are no more records from the API call, stop the loop.

But that whole block feels really bulky. Is there some way to rewrite that so it's more concise?

Comment: what is so bulky about this loop? I find it to be concise & easily comprehendible.

Comment: So `ThirdPartyApi.all` doesn't actually return all, it only returns 100 at a time?

Comment: @MarkThomas That's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Since you want to do other statements in the loop, here's one suggestion:

```
offset = 0
begin
  offset += 100
  count = ThirdPartyApi.all(offset: offset)

  # Do other things within the loop
end until count.zero?
```

This is not significantly shorter, but by putting the test at the end of the loop it makes it more clear that it will always execute at least once. This also saves you from having to initialize `count`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have any other use for `count` you can reduce this to:

```
offset = 0
offset += 100 until ThirdPartyApi.all(offset: offset) == 0
```

**Update**: The above version is not the same as the OP's original post, since

```
<statement> until <expression>
```

does *not* execute statement before the first evaluation of `<expression>`, unlike

```
begin
  ...
end until <expression>
```

which *does* execute the `begin ... end` before evaluating the `until` clause. (See http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/6745 for an interesting comment from matz on this subject, referred to by http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language).

Given the revised question, which indicates the OP wants to execute additional code within the loop, I have nothing to add beyond the answer from @Matt (who I have to thank for pointing out my error in the original answer.)

Comment: Would that break once count equals zero (which was the core terminating condition of the original loop)?

Comment: Updated to reflect error in my original post, as pointed out by @Matt.